# iOS Share Extension opens on simulator iPad; does not open on hardware iPad running iOS 8

Tags: ios, ipad, hardware, ios8, ios-app-extension

I'm currently making a share extension using Xcode 6.5. I was previously testing with only simulators and everything was working great. Today I tried running on a hardware iPad running iOS 8 and discovered my share extension does not even open.

I am frustrated since my debugger won't attach to the extension, so I can't look at logs or set breakpoints. I tried making a dummy app with a share extension, and that worked on BOTH the simulator and hardware iPad, so its not a just a problem with the hardware. Not really sure what the problem is...

Help?

Answer (score 1):

It was because under the Build Settings for my Share Extension, under Architectures, I was only using armv7. Using Standard architectures (armv7, arm64) solved my problem.

Comment: This won't be the reason in all cases. Mine already had arm64. A suggestion from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837479/ios-8-today-extension-not-working-on-device, is to comment out code until it at least displays. I'm upgrading IOS to 8.1.1 at the moment, hoping that will fix it. I will also try disabling app groups.

Answer (score 1):

Wait a bit longer the first time it runs (~15 seconds) if you are are debugging on a physical device. It could be something else too, but at least wait this long. Once it does show, if you click cancel and then try and again it will be almost instant.

I also found that `self.textView.editable = false` (I had this in the `configurationItems` function override) doesn't work on a physical device, only the simulator.